# next.js how to pass data to a page

Tags: next.js

Hi guys I'm learning some next.js and I'm trying to pass data from a data.js file to a page in the pages folder. I tried using `getStaticProps` but that needs an absolute URL. Below ill show an example of what I'm trying to do. Firstly is the page itself.

```
const page = ({ data }) => {

  return (
    <>
      <p>{data.name}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default page;
```

Then the data.js file looks like such.

```
export const user = [
    {
        id: 'Banana1',
        password: 'Apple123',
        name: 'Banana',
        surname: 'Orange',
        birthday: '10 March 2077',
        cellNumber: '011 111 1111',
        email: 'Banana@apple.com',
    }
]
```

I know there is probably better methods of keeping the data but I'm just looking for something really simple for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If this is a local file. Just do `import data from '../path/to/datafile'` and access `data.name`

Comment: I tried this and I get an error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: Update your export like this `export default const user = [...]` or you can update your import like so `import { user } from '../path/to/datafile'` and then `user.name`

Comment: Okay, I changed the import and removed the prop from the `const page = ({ data }) =>` and that then loads the page without the error but it doesn't display the data.

Comment: How do you call the `<Page />` component? How do you pass the data in?

Comment: the "page.js" is in the pages folder and in my Navbar component I have a `<Link href="/profile"> <a className={navStyles.profileLink}>Your Profile</a> </Link>` but im trying to pull the data directly into the "page.js"

Comment: Can you create a sandbox and update your question ?

Comment: Sorry, but how would I go about making a sandbox?

Comment: @trash_dev Your `user` variable is an array, to access the data in the object you need to use `user[0].name`.

Comment: @juliomalves Thank you sir, that solved my issue. I feel silly for not seeing that.

Comment: @juliomalves correct! idk why I thought he was mapping over data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @trash_dev I added the `import { user } from '../path/to/datafile'` in the page.js and also in the page.js removed the `({ data })` as that wasn't needed.

Then with help from @juliomalves when trying to use the data the array position had to be used so in my example it would  be as follows:

```
const page = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <p>{user[0].name}</p>
    </>
  );
};
```